# An expression treated like a total derivative that is not a total derivative.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For any smooth function $g$ defined on an open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, we define

> $g_i(u):=\int_0^1\frac{\partial g}{\partial u^i}(tu) dt$.

My text claims that this implies that $g=g(0)+\sum g_iu^i$. I've tried manipulating this but since it isn't quite a total derivative, I can't derive this result. I always end up with an extra factor of $t$ in the integrand which would be avoided if the derivative were something different (something like $\partial g/\partial( t u^i)$ may be).

Is one possibility is that this is an error, or may be the notation means that this is a total derivative? The book is [Lee](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/gsm-107). The link doesn't list any errata for the chapter, but it was updated in 2012.

EDIT: I forgot to mention $U$ is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what is $\frac{d}{dt} g(tu)$ ?

Answer: 
$$ \frac{d}{dt} g(tu) = \frac{d}{dt} g(tu^1, \dots, tu^n) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{\partial(tu^i)}{{\partial t}} \frac{\partial g}{\partial u^i}(tu^1, \dots, tu^n) = \sum_{i=0}^n u^i \frac{\partial g}{\partial u^i}(tu^1, \dots, tu^n)$$

It follows that 
$$g(u) - g(0) = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{d}{dt} g(tu)\right)\,dt = \sum_{i=0}^{n} u^i g_i$$

I'm assuming your open set is star-shaped around the origin (so that for any $u\in U$, $tu \in U$ for all $t\in [0,1]$).

Comment: We have that $\frac{d g}{d t}=\sum \frac{\partial g}{\partial (u^i t)} \frac{d(u^i t)}{d t}=\sum \frac{\partial g}{\partial (u^i t)}u^i.$ Also, $\sum \frac{\partial g}{\partial u^i}u^i=\sum \frac{\partial g}{\partial (u^j t)} \frac{d(u^j t)}{d u^i}u^i=\sum \frac{\partial g}{\partial (u^j t)}\delta^j_i u^i t=\sum \frac{\partial g}{\partial (u^i t)} u^i t=\frac{d g}{d t} t $. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it's nonsense. For instance $\frac{\partial g}{\partial tu_i}$ does not make any sense. You need to learn how to apply the chain rule properly.

Comment: Alright, I understand my mistake now, I was misunderstanding what was happening. Of course, we defined $g(u)$ with $u\in U$. I was interpreting $\frac{\partial g(t u)}{\partial u^i}$ as parametrizing $g$ with $ut$ _and then_ taking a derivative w.r.t. $u^i$, which actually doesn't make sense. Instead, we take a derivative and then parametrize with $ut$. That's why I wrote $\partial g/\partial (u^i t)$, I was trying to take derivative with respect to the argument. Anyway, thanks, I feel better.